# Telerik MVC ASPX ClientTemplate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I need to convert this to ASPX formate.

```
ClientTemplate(@"<a href=""/EditOffLine/Edit?id=<#= ItemId #>"">Edit</a>")
```

My column Template is:

```
  columns.Template(item => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditOffLine", new { id = item.ID })).Title("Edit").Width(10);
```

When I sort or filter the grid, Edit will be lost?  I think the client Template would help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I Found the answer, here it is just in case someone is having the same issue:  ClientTemplate(Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditOffLine", new { id = "<#= ID #>" }).ToString());

Comment: you can answer your own question and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the answer, here it is just in case someone is having the same issue: ClientTemplate(Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditOffLine", new { id = "<#= ID #>" }).ToString())